# Android Studio asking for Github account every commit-push, rejecting username-password accepting tokens only

Tags: android, android-studio, github

On push I get a github prompt which rejects user/pass combination with a 404. The workaround I found for these is to use tokens.

Well, I can't keep re-generating the token just so I can push since it asks for an account everytime.

1. Why is Android Studio not using the Github account specified in the settings->Version Control->Github. I added this via token so it could use it when pushing, but instead asks me for github login for every single push?
2. Also, why is it rejecting my username password on the push prompt with a 404? These tiny issues combined make up a big problem of me generating a token every time I want to push.

I'm at wits end

Comment: Let me guess. You're facing it after changing the GitHub token to the latest format?

Comment: @AnggrayudiH sorry not sure what you mean. I just pull a token as instructed by AndroidStudio. Which baffled me since I'm using PyCharm and didn't have issue adding my GitHub account

Comment: Same issue with me